# Reference a variable value in another cell as part of formula

Tags: excel

**SHORT QUESTION**

Ive got a formula `=IF(ISBLANK(Q.1!C71),"",Q.1!C71)` im trying to be able to set a control cell / variable so instead of `C71` it would reference `c*$B$1*`, `*$B$1*` being my reference / control cell / variable in the same sheet as this formula, any ideas how to do this ?

---

**LONG QUESTION**

Ive got a spreadsheet that is regularly provided by a 3rd part with different data in it each time, although the column order of the data is always the same.

To get the data into my spreadsheet, i create another tab in the same workbook as their sheet and reference the data in their spreadsheet in a sheet i call import template sheet, i then from there copy and paste the import sheet into my spreadsheet, as all the columns match.

To reorder their columns in a non destructive way i use the following formula in my import template sheet, for instance if i wanted their column C, in my sheets column F i would place this in F1 and the pull the cell down so it does this for all rows :

`=IF(ISBLANK(Q.1!C71),"",Q.1!C71)` (the ifblank just helps sanitise the data by not throwing #ref if there is no data in the cell.)

The issue i have is that i have around 30 columns to re order and although the column structure is the same, there is sometimes some 'header' data (basically a text summary) at the top of the document of varying length, so instead of the first row i need being `71` sometimes it might be row `50` or row `90`...

To speed things up id like to be able to have a control number / variable cell where i can set a variable for the starting row, and then reference that in my cell, so that i dont have the go and edit the formula in 30 different columns.

Comment: Check out `OFFSET` or possibly `INDIRECT`.  Both allow you to specify a number in a cell that can then be used to create a reference to a different cell.  `OFFSET` is probably easier to use in this example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the starting row of the reference by putting a number in cell `B1`, that would look something like this:

**B1**

```
71
```

**Referencing Cell**

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Q.1!C"&B1),"",INDIRECT("Q.1!C"&B1))
```

`INDIRECT` allows you to build a string representation of a cell reference and then get the value of that cell. So we build a string reference using the value of B1, and then use `INDIRECT` to get the value of that string's referenced cell.